# why when I insert a new table all of others tables loses its configurations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

In my script I create new formatted tables in Docs, but when it runs all of the other tables in the document loses its formatting. I can't figure it out why it happens

here's my code:

```
function insert(n, alternativo=false){
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  
  var documento = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  
  if (alternativo == false){
    var fluxo = 'básico';
    }else{
      var fluxo = 'alternativo';
    }
  var table = [['N°', '[CT'+n+']- Caso de uso - Fluxo '+fluxo],
               ['Pré-condições', ''],
               ['Passos', ''],
               ['Critério de êxito', '']];
  
  documento.appendTable(table);
  var tabela = documento.getTables()[0];
  tabela.setColumnWidth(0, 105);
  
  for(j=0; j<4; j++){
    var celula = tabela.getCell(j, 0).getChild(0).asParagraph();
    celula.setAttributes(style);
  }
  var celula = tabela.getCell(0, 1).getChild(0).asText();
  celula.setAttributes(style); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `In my script I create new formatted tables in Docs, but when it runs all of the other tables in the document loses its formatting.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By the way, it seems that in your script the attribute is always reflected to the 1st table in the Document. How about this?

Comment: Now i see... The other tables doesn't losses its formatting. What happens its that the script its not even formatting them, its only formatting the first table. Thanks for your helping!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.